# Woo commerce rest api get all product for customer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to get all product using bearer token(using JWT Plugin).
Using admin token fetching the all products but when using customer token not fetching the product data.

```
call: /wp-json/wc/v3/products
```

response:

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

img:
[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Gu0.png)

Comment: I am having the same issue if get the token from a customer user, if I get from administrator user is working fine. If anyone has the solution I'd appreciate it.

Comment: my question too

Answer (score 0):

Just use https instead of http in your weblink

Answer (score 0):

403 means you do not have permission to access the resource. I installed a role and permission manager plugin and gave "`READ PRIVATE PRODUCTS`" permission to "`customer`" role.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
wc-api/v3/products.
```

change `wp-json/wc` to `wc-api`.